# Use project class referenced by referenced project

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I Log In from the main page and press the button to go to another project.
I want to use Login information in another project.

```
uSERTTableAdapter.FillBy(dsLogin1.USERT, txtId.Text, txtPass.Text);
UserName = dsLogin1.USERT.Rows[0]["USER_NAME"].ToString();
```

I try reference, but main project referred another project.

I can't reference on another project to main project.

I declare variable, user_name in public class in main project.

How can I do?

Comment: Use a third project that contains the classes that are required by both other projects?

Comment: umm.. I will try your solution!